# Accessing variables from outside of class

Tags: php

I'm having an issue trying to figure out an effective of doing this.
Suppose I have a language file called `fr.php` wher some variables exist in there as:

```
$lang["W_TYPE"]["COMPLETE"] = "Completé";
$lang["W_TYPE"]["INCOMPLETE"] = "Incomplet";
$lang["W_TYPE"]["BO"] = "En attente";
```

Now suppose I have a method in one of my classes that needs to access some of these variables.

```
public function getCompletion($string = true)
{
    $x = $this->COMPLETION;
    if($string)
    {
        echo $lang["W_TYPE"]["COMPLETE"];
        if($x==self::ORDER_COMPLETE)
        {
            return "<font class='jobComplete'>".$lang["W_TYPE"]["COMPLETE"]." &#x2713;</font>";
        }
        elseif($x==self::INCOMPLETE)
        {
            return "<font class='jobIncomplete'>".$lang["W_TYPE"]["INCOMPLETE"]."...</font>";
        }
        elseif($x==self::BACK_ORDER)
        {
            return "<font class='backOrder'>".$lang["W_TYPE"]["BO"]."...</font>";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return $x;  
    }
}
```

The above is not possible of course, but I've actually run out of options on how to do something like this in the most effective way. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked into calling `include 'fr.php'` within `getCompletion()`?

Comment: Why not pass `$lang` into the constructor of the class?

Comment: In general if a function or class needs something to do it's job that is a dependency. Dependencies should be provided to the object instead of relying on the environment to provide them.

Comment: Very nice way to put it. Usually when I'm building my projects, the classes are made, and then nothing in them is changed after. Only the main script that is calling them is ever changed from that point on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your class looks somewhat like this:

```
<?php
class CompleteClass
{

    function __construct($lang)
    {
        $this->lang = $lang;
    }

    public function getCompletion($string = true)
    {
        $lang = $this->lang;
        $x    = $this->COMPLETION;
        if ($string) {
            echo $lang["W_TYPE"]["COMPLETE"];
            if ($x == self::ORDER_COMPLETE) {
                return "<font class='jobComplete'>" . $lang["W_TYPE"]["COMPLETE"] . " &#x2713;</font>";
            } elseif ($x == self::INCOMPLETE) {
                return "<font class='jobIncomplete'>" . $lang["W_TYPE"]["INCOMPLETE"] . "...</font>";
            } elseif ($x == self::BACK_ORDER) {
                return "<font class='backOrder'>" . $lang["W_TYPE"]["BO"] . "...</font>";
            }
        } else {
            return $x;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

You can get the language file from the constructor while creating the class.

You should also have `fr.php`, as well as all your other language files return the array at the end. That way it can be utilized by the main script without having to know the variable name in question.

fr.php

```
$lang["W_TYPE"]["COMPLETE"] = "Completé";
$lang["W_TYPE"]["INCOMPLETE"] = "Incomplet";
$lang["W_TYPE"]["BO"] = "En attente";
return $lang;
```

You can create the class in another file like this now:

```
<?php
    $lang = require_once 'fr.php';
    $completeClass = new CompleteClass($lang);
    echo $completeClass->getCompletion(true);
?>
```

Comment: IMHO I think this is the correct solution. Only Addition I would make would be to add the `return $lang;` within the fr.php like @JonathandeM states in his answer, this way you don't have to care what the variable is called in the fr.php file.

Comment: I do believe this is the best option. My only concern is that I'd have to modify every single instance for this object in the entire site... This was one of the reasons why I got stuck on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

fr.php Notice the `return $lang;`

```
$lang["W_TYPE"]["COMPLETE"] = "Completé";
$lang["W_TYPE"]["INCOMPLETE"] = "Incomplet";
$lang["W_TYPE"]["BO"] = "En attente";
return $lang;
```

Other file Notice the `$lang = require_once 'fr.php';`

```
public function getCompletion($string = true)
{
    $lang = require 'fr.php';
    $x = $this->COMPLETION;
    if($string)
    {
        echo $lang["W_TYPE"]["COMPLETE"];
        if($x==self::ORDER_COMPLETE)
        {
            return "<font class='jobComplete'>".$lang["W_TYPE"]["COMPLETE"]." &#x2713;</font>";
        }
        elseif($x==self::INCOMPLETE)
        {
            return "<font class='jobIncomplete'>".$lang["W_TYPE"]["INCOMPLETE"]."...</font>";
        }
        elseif($x==self::BACK_ORDER)
        {
            return "<font class='backOrder'>".$lang["W_TYPE"]["BO"]."...</font>";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return $x;  
    }
}
```

Comment: require_once is this context is not good... $lang would not be preserved from one call to the next but would throw a fatal on the second invokation.